# Referencing count index in another module

Tags: terraform

I have this Terraform module:

```
locals {
  name = "${var.counter > 0 ? lower(format("%v-%d", var.name, var.counter+1)) : lower(format("%v", var.name))}"
}

resource "null_resource" "default" {
  count = "${var.enabled == "true" ? 1 : 0}"

  triggers = {
    id         = "${lower(join(var.delimiter, compact(concat(list(var.namespace, var.stage, local.name, var.attributes))))}"
    name       = "${local.name}"
    namespace  = "${lower(format("%v", var.namespace))}"
    stage      = "${lower(format("%v", var.stage))}"
    attributes = "${lower(format("%v", join(var.delimiter, compact(var.attributes))))}"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I'm using the module as such:

```
module "label" {
  source         = "../modules/tf-label"
  namespace      = "${var.namespace}"
  stage          = "${var.stage}"
  name           = "${var.name}"
  attributes     = "${var.attributes}"
  delimiter      = "${var.delimiter}"
  tags           = "${merge(map("AZ", "${local.availability_zone}"), var.tags)}"
  enabled        = "${local.instance_count > 0 ? "true" : "false"}"
}
```

I am using it with the following resource:

```
resource "aws_instance" "default" {
  count = "${var.instance_count}"
  name = "${module.label.id}"
  tags = "${module.label.tags}"
}
```

Since the `aws_instance` resource can be more than 1, how do I pass the `count.index` value to the *label* module (e.g. `var.counter`) so I can process it and form the proper label (e.g. `namespace-stage-name-attributes-counter` --> `example-prod-app-nginx-1`) or what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: Use the count attribute on the module block. Feed the count over the module block into the module as a variable counter. Index into the module output in the instance resource block - The module block will now yield an array of module nodes rather than a single module node so we index into it to get the one we want.

```tf
module "aws_instance_label" {
    source         = "../modules/tf-label"
    count          = "${var.instance_count}"
    counter        = "${count.index}"
    namespace      = "${var.namespace}"
    stage          = "${var.stage}"
    name           = "${var.name}"
    attributes     = "${var.attributes}"
    delimiter      = "${var.delimiter}"
    tags           = "${merge(map("AZ", "${local.availability_zone}"), var.tags)}"
    enabled        = "${local.instance_count > 0 ? "true" : "false"}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "default" {
    count = "${var.instance_count}"
    name = "${module.aws_instance_label[count.index].id}"
    tags = "${module.aws_instance_label[count.index].tags}"
}
```